# Regular Expressions Preg_Replace() Replacing Exact String

Tags: php, regex

I want to use `preg_replace()` to replace anywhere in a string `%z` with `&#378;`

So I wrote:

```
$pattern = array();
$pattern[0] = '/^\%z$/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = '/\&#378;/';

string = "oraz ró%znego typu innych wydarzen kulturalnych, sportowych i rozrywkowych."
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
echo $string;
```

The above example is not working. I'm new to regular expressions so I'm not quite sure what I did wrong.

Any advice would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: You don't need to use a regex for that. str_replace do it better.

Answer (score 1):

Remove anchors `^ and $` from your regex pattern since `%z` is not at start or end of the input:

```
$pattern[0] = '/%z/';
```

Also you don't need to provide regex delimiters in replacement and neither do you need to escape `%` or `&` so this will work:

```
$replacements[0] = '&#378;'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues, some of which have no effect:

- `%` does not need to be escaped
- `^` and `$` anchor the start and end of the string.  Remove them: `/%z/`
- You are using `$replacement` in the function call rather than `$replacements`.
- Since you are only doing one replacement, an array is unnecessary.
- You should not include PCRE delimiters in the replacement.  It is a string rather than a regular expression.  Simply write it as `&#378;`

You can also do a simple string replacement by replacing `preg_replace` with `str_replace`.  Just remove the delimiters from `pattern`.

Comment: Good catch on the parse error. Wonder how long it would have took me to see that one. :P

Answer (score 1):

In your expression, you don't need to use the beginning of string `^` anchor or the end of string `$` anchor because `%z` is not at either place in your string, the `%` and `&` characters also do not need to be escaped here, and since this is a simple replacement I see no need to use an array to accomplish this task.

You can use `str_replace` for this.

```
$string = 'oraz ró%znego typu innych wydarzen kulturalnych, sportowych i rozrywkowych.';
$string = str_replace('%z', '&#378;', $string);
echo $string;
```

Using the cheaper version, `strtr` (You can put multiple patterns and replacements in an array)

```
$string = 'oraz ró%znego typu innych wydarzen kulturalnych, sportowych i rozrywkowych.';
$string = strtr($string, array('%z' => '&#378;'));
echo $string;
```

And if you still decide to use a regular expression to do this.

```
$string = 'oraz ró%znego typu innych wydarzen kulturalnych, sportowych i rozrywkowych.';
$string = preg_replace('/%z/i', '&#378;', $string);
echo $string;
```

Output

```
oraz ró&#378;nego typu innych wydarzen kulturalnych, sportowych i rozrywkowych.
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me the different ways to solve this problem. :) Cheers!

Comment: Glad I could help also.